# OrientDB corruption in Nexus Repository version 3.1

Tags: orientdb, nexus3

We are using **Nexus Repository 3.1.0** (official docker image) and **orientdb** seems to be corrupted.

Nexus is no longer starting, and started getting the following errors in nexus.log :

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSchemaException: Cluster with 
id 19 already belongs to class bucket
```

We can't access to orientdb console, nexus-orient-console.jar doesn't exist in version 3.1.0 (available since Nexus 3.2.1 and Newer according the Nexus support : [Accessing the OrientDB Console](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002930827-Accessing-the-OrientDB-Console))

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of OrientDB are you using?

Comment: Version of orientdb is 2.2.11 (in nexus-bundles)

Comment: Have you tried with another version?